# should a global animate class with > *, > * > *, etc.. work for giving quick animations to :change states?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I came up with the idea to have a class as follows:

```
.animate,.animate>*,.animate>*>*,.animate>*>*>*,.animate>*>*>*>*,.animate>*>*>*>*>*,.animate>*>*>*>*>*>*,.animate*>*>*>*>*>*>*>, {
-webkit-transition: color .3s ease, opacity .3s ease, .3s ease;
-moz-transition: color .3s ease, opacity .3s ease, .3s ease;
-ms-transition: color .3s ease, opacity .3s ease, .3s ease;
transition: color .3s ease, opacity .3s ease, .3s ease;
```

}

so that I can just chuck a class="animate etc.." on any div and anything inside it will get these animations by default. It just doesn't work though, and I remember I had it working at some stage but it just stopped over night. Theoretically it should work yes?

Comment: `.animate*>*>*>*>*>*>*>, `? You have syntax errors in your selector. Comma and the last selector.

Comment: ohh okay, wow. Thank-you very much, I thought that might be the case :/ sorry for the waste of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select any child elements after the `.animate` class just use:

```
.animate * {
    // Those rules apply to any child element of .animate
    -webkit-transition: color .3s ease, opacity .3s ease, .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: color .3s ease, opacity .3s ease, .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: color .3s ease, opacity .3s ease, .3s ease;
    transition: color .3s ease, opacity .3s ease, .3s ease;
}
```

Comment: and children of those children?

Comment: Yes, any children and any children of those, and so on.

Comment: hmm, I had to add a bunch of >* and >*>* etc.. classes for it to affect children of children, you're sure?

Comment: Yes, sure. The > expression indicates a *direct* child, of the selector before, without it, it indicates any child; per se `div > direct child`, and `div any child`.

Comment: hmm well it doesn't apply the styles properly then, I'll look around. Thanks for the time :)